# Unable to import wfdb in jupyter notebook after pip install --user wfdb

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I tried to install the `wdfb` module to work on the `MIT-BIH dataset` using the command `pip install --user wfdb` on the terminal. The `wfdb` module has been installed successfully on my localhost.

However, when I try to use the command `import wfdb` on a jupyter notebook hosted on localhost, it throws the following error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 9>()
      6 import shutil
      7 import posixpath
----> 9 import wfdb

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wfdb'
```

I use `anaconda`, so I tried to solve this problem using the anaconda prompt and typing the following commands one by one:

```
conda install -c conda-forge wfdb
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 wfdb
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 wfdb
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 wfdb
```

as instructed here: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/wfdb

However, this again throws the following error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed                                                                                                                                                                                     CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json>                                                                                                                        Elapsed: -                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.                                                                HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.                                        'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64'
```

The above problem persists even after retrying the commands several times.

How do I go about solving this problem so that I can import `wfdb` correctly and proceed with my work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I can strongly recommend to use Mamba for the installation of packages:

```
conda install -c conda-forge mamba
```

Then, only use one of the suggested sources to install `wfdb`.

```
mamba install -c conda-forge wfdb
```

Does this help?